# How to add and remove apps post-creation on LiveUSB?

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

I've generated multiple 18.04.2 and 18.04.3 LiveUSBs with persistence, but have not been able to permanently remove original apps (in particular, Amazon, Mines, Solitaire, and Thunderbird) by selecting to delete them from the GNOME GUI.

Also, I launched Software and Updates, set the Download source (to mirror.uoregon.edu), added *Community-maintained free and open source software (universe)*, then installed two apps with:

```
sudo apt install stress stress-ng
```

After rebooting, stress and stress-ng were gone; Amazon, Thunderbird, and games  were back.

The LiveUSBs were generated by the Pendrive.com Unversal USB Installer (1.9.8.2) and Unetbootin 6.6.1 (as well as other apps no longer supported).

How may I do this post hoc, without the [Custom Build](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) process, perhaps by flushing the changes to *casper-rw*?

Comment: Do you want to remove apps, that are part of the original system (that come with the iso file), or do you want to remove apps, that *you* installed (and are stored in the `casper-rw`file?

Comment: Right now I tested in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS persistent live created with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb): I could remove and re-install `usb-creator-gtk`, and I could install and remove `htop`. In other words, I did not reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have not time tonight to test with 18.04.3 LTS, but hope to do it  tomorrow.

Comment: @K7AAY: With a Persistent drive, the root is generally part of a read only file system, either an ISO9660 partition, squash file or ISO file. The only way to delete apts is to remaster the ISO file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis of the problem

It seems that you did not run persistent live systems, but live-only systems, where you installed and removed items. This works while the systems are running, but the modifications do not persist, they are gone after reboot.

- Maybe your USB drives have the capability to boot in persistent mode, but you have booted and/or rebooted them live-only. The boot option `persistent` makes the difference.
- Maybe the tools that you used are not yet upgraded to work for persistence in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
- Maybe you missed some minor detail in the instructions ...

### Working alternative

I downloaded `ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` and used [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a persistent live drive in a 16 GB USB3 pendrive.

When booted persistent live I installed `htop` and removed `usb-creator-gtk` (like I did with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS as described in a previous comment), and then did [part of] what you describe in your edited question: removed Thunderbird, removed the button for Amazon, connected to Universe and installed `stress` and `stress-ng`.

It worked, the modifications persist after reboot. The following picture illustrates what it looks like.

[image]

Please notice that you can reboot a persistent live drive made with mkusb live-only, and then it will not see the modifications. The original system from the iso file is still there, but you can mount the `casper-rw` partition and see the files, where the modifications are stored.

Comment: Also affected 18.04.2

Comment: Is it important to solve the problem with Pendrive.com Unversal USB Installer (1.9.8.2) and Unetbootin 6.6.1 or would it work to use another tool? (I am rather sure that mkusb will work for you in 18.04.2 too).